# String to hexadecimal Color Code

Tags: php

in a project I'm making I'm using numerous color codes.
the point is not for them to be Beautiful, just differents.(I also want to be able to constantly have the same colors code for the same fields on refresh (no Random color generators))
I was thinking about taking the name of the fields and turn them to Hex color.
Is there a pre-defined function for this?

Exemple :

```
$string = "Blablabla";
$colorCode = toColorCode($string);

function toColorCode($initial){
    /*MAGIC MADNESS*/
    return array("R"=>XXX,"G"=>XXX,"B"=>XXX);
}
```

FORGOT TO MENTION : it's important that the values are Numbers only.

Comment: On a side note is this a good idea from a UI design point of view? How will you make sure your text has a decent contrast with the background? I doubt anyone will appreciate yellow text on white background

Comment: Two questions: 
1. What exactly are you expecting as an argument to toColorCode()? A word, 'white', or a hex code, 'FFFFFF'?
2. Is there a reason that you need to return an array of values instead of the actual hex code?

Comment: so, you want to turn strings like "FF5600" into 0xFF5600?

Comment: @ManosDilaverakis if he puts this just a legend color it won't be that bad.

Comment: @ManosDilaverakis that's where the importance of an array come. i can select Red Blue for 1 categorie and set Green to a fix value. i could also force a minimum value on one of the field etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can understand, you want to generate a fairly unique color code for a string.

The easies way is to call a checksum function on the string, for example MD5:

```
function toColorCode($initial){
  $checksum = md5($initial);
  return array(
    "R" => hexdec(substr($checksum, 0, 2)),
    "G" => hexdec(substr($checksum, 2, 2)),
    "B" => hexdec(substr($checksum, 4, 2))
  );
}
```

Comment: would be good if MD5 returns only numerical characters, sry i forgot to mention.

Comment: Wrap the substr: `hexdec(substr($checksum, 0, 2))`

Comment: Thanks justin, didn't tought about it. that fixed my problem!